# Custom error message from post_save signal

Tags: python, django, django-signals, django-messages

Ok so Im saving a CSV document to a Machine object. I want to notifiy the user that the Machine does not exist if it does not exist and exit the save. I first read the CSV file to see what machine the document is for by reading a serial number row.

In my signals:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=CSVDocument)
def read_file(sender,instance, signal, created, **kwargs):
    ...
    machine = Machine.objects.get(serial_number=sn)
    if not machine:
        customNotificationMessage in admin tempalte
```

I do not want to raise an exception at this stage, rather tell the user there is no such machine, so first create the machine.

Currently if I take out the try block to lookupt the machine it raises the exception:

```
Machine matching query does not exist. Lookup parameters were {'serial_number': 'NEC03610154'}
```

I would actually just want this execption as part of the messages after the file is saved.

Comment: Just change the `get` into `filter`

Answer (score 0):

Just catch that exception and print the message out:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=CSVDocument)
def read_file(sender,instance, signal, created, **kwargs):
    ...
    try:
        machine = Machine.objects.get(serial_number=sn)
    exception Machine.DoesNotExist:
        machine = None
        error_message = 'Machine matching query does not exist'
    if not machine:
        customNotificationMessage in admin template
        print error_message
```

Another option is to use `filter()` instead of `get()`:

```
machine = Machine.objects.filter(serial_number=sn)
```

You will get an empty queryset if there is no match.

Hope it helps.